# Eliminate low score from solr answer

Tags: search, solr, soundex

Really is it possible to filter out low score from solr results?

This is a very helpful thing, even if documentation advise against it.

Let's say that I am doing a search after 4 fields, like

- field 1
- field 2
- field 3
- field 4

and then merge all this in to another filed and do some soundex filter.

field 5 soundex

Well it is happen that sometimes a word is found only in the 5th field base on soundex, but the score is usually very very low. So in this case is safe to discard the result.

And then how can I do this in a simple way; is it possible?

Comment: If you don't want to include hits only in the last field when filtering, use the last field as a boost instead of including it in the query?

Comment: That's really a good idea. I can use it... But still if I am doing a phonetic search and I use that phonetic search just as a boost, I loos all results if there is a typo in the search term.